# Circular lists in generators

Tags: python, python-3.x

Propose `s = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

If you `zip(s, s[1:])` which returns `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]`. 
Is it possible to rewrite `zip(s, s[1:])` to return `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]`?

Or for generality sake, is it possible to zip a list with itself for the last touple to be `(list[-1], list[0])`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for handy iterators to accomplish this rather elegantly:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(zip(s, islice(cycle(s), 1, None)))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Note, `itertools.cycle` works like this:

> `cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D ...`

It is an infinite iterator, so be careful. `zip` here stops at the shortest, so it works fine.

Also, `itertools.islice`:

> `islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G`

Which works just like `slice` or sequence slicing, i.e. `my_list[1:] == my_list[1:None] == my_list[slice(1, None)]` except it works on *any iterable*, not just sequences.

Anyway, note this approach is generalizable:

```
>>> list(zip(s, islice(cycle(s), 2, None)))
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2)]
>>> list(zip(s, islice(cycle(s), 3, None)))
[(1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3)]
>>> list(zip(s, islice(cycle(s), 4, None)))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools as it


iterable = [1, 2, 3, 4]

c = it.cycle(iterable)
next(c)

list(zip(iterable, c))
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> zip(s, s[1:] + s[:1])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: You mean `[s[0]]`.

Comment: @Piinthesky or `s[0:1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Looks indeed more consistent and is therefore better.

Answer (score 0):

a pure python cyclic `zip` answer can be made with a parameterized slice indexing, adding the slices

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4]

n = 2

list(zip(s[n::] + s[0:n], s[n+1::] + s[0:n+1]))
Out[100]: [(3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]

n = 0

list(zip(s[n::] + s[0:n], s[n+1::] + s[0:n+1]))
Out[101]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
```